# Samba - Is there a way to allow a group only to view\edit\write certain folders, under one share?

Tags: linux, centos, samba

Is there anyway I can allow a group only to see only certain (two) folders in a directory I wish to share?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Windows and Linux work under the assumption that you can see anything in a directory you have access to, but getting past that point is up to the ACLs on that directory.

In a pure Windows environment, Server 2003r2 and later has something called "Access Based Enumeration". When enabled on a share, it will only display folders that users have some kind of access into. The classic example is a homes share.

```
\\winsrv\homes\
```

With ABE, users would only see "\winserv\homes\myusername", where without ABE they'd see the entire user list.

This is handled at the share level, not the rights level. Your Samba config will need the following lines on your share definition should emulate this behavior:

```
hide unwriteable = yes
hide unreadable = yes
```

These will hide directories that can't be read/written by the user, based on their access rights.